# Uninstall package from repair mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit on my server.

I installed resolvconf in an attempt to change resolv.conf without it being overwritten. It was all going well until I rebooted my VPS and it wouldn't come online. I have to uninstall resolvconf in order to get it back online.

My VPS provider allows me to put the VPS in repair mode which puts my VPS files in /repair. How can I uninstall resolvconf from there?

I tried doing this, but that won't work ofcourse since it's in repair mode.

```
sudo apt-get remove resolvconf
```

Comment: You can probably chroot yourself into /repair and then uninstall via apt-get.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by executing the following commands.

```
chroot /repair
apt-get remove resolvconf
exit
```